# JS: Why Is This Slower? It Shouldn't Test Other OR Conditions But It Does?

Tags: javascript, performance, conditional-statements

I just tested something. I always thought that in a OR condition, once the computer/browser finds something true, it returns it and doesn't test the other conditions. I structured my code around this assumption.

However, I timed it and it appears that the long test takes x4 more times, any explanation for that?

Note: Tested in Google Chrome console.

JSPerf:

http://jsperf.com/or-condition `return true || 1`

http://jsperf.com/or-condition2 `var condition = true || 1; return condition;`

http://jsperf.com/or-condition3 `if(true || 1) return true` Seems relatively faster.

EDIT: I just found how that the amount of conditions after the true is not important. What matters is the length of the condition. Check http://jsperf.com/or-condition5.

My theory is that the browser splits the function into 2+ different memory zones because of its length. When it calls the function, it needs to get data from multiple memory zones instead of 1.

```
a = function(){
    return true ||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1||1;
}
b = function(){
    return true;
}
//#############################################

var start = Date.now();
for(var i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; i++){
    a();
}   var end = Date.now();       
console.log(end-start);     //3075


var start = Date.now();
for(var i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; i++){
    b();
}   var end = Date.now();       
console.log(end-start);     //776
```

Comment: In jsfiddle, my additional OR values aren't being evaluated:
http://jsfiddle.net/e5BRj/

Comment: Even if it doesn't trigger the function, it still takes more time... I made a JSperf for it. http://jsperf.com/or-condition

Comment: [For demonstration purposes](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/2fFYW/)...

Comment: Interesting. Could it be that the `return` command evaluates whole expressions? Try the same test with `var condition = true || b() || b()...etc` and then `return condition`. This question intrigues me. +1

Comment: @shennan Just tried it and it doesn't change the speed. http://jsperf.com/or-condition2

Comment: Considering that the `b` test runs over a billion times per second on my computer, I'm betting that the call is optimized away entirely, so nothing actually takes place.

Comment: @cookiemonster Even by adding a non-trivial command, 2nd code runs much faster. http://jsperf.com/or-condition4

Comment: @cookiemonster Possibly, but giving the `b` method a shot of adrenaline with a simple `Math.random()` [doesn't change things much](http://jsperf.com/or-investigation2)...

Comment: @RainingChain: Why do you think this is non-trivial? [The compiler always is smarter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65-RbBwZQdU). Unless your code looks too dumb to be optimizable.

Comment: In IE9, results are the same (more–or–less) for both functions. Likely IE is using the obvious, non–optimised algorithm for both functions and results are as expected.

Comment: These types of questions are pointless, all they reallly test are compiler optimistations, and even then only by guessing based on outcomes. The next version of whatever browser may turn the results on their head. Or not.

Comment: @RobG I don't think that the question is pointless. It ***has*** highlighted the pitfalls of microbenchmarking. That, in itself, is value enough. Unless you can claim that ***all*** benchmarking is pointless, this question is still a good indication that there is a line to be drawn somewhere.

Comment: Those additions to the test brought the results much closer, or made them basically identical on my machine depending on which one. @RobG is right. There's no good, solid, correct answer to questions like this. It comes down to the individual optimizations present at the time of testing.

Comment: @shennan: But the point of the question was to get an answer, and there is no real answer. Sure we can say that we've learned or enforced tangentially related lessons from it having been asked, but within the context of StackOverflow, these sorts of questions aren't great.

Comment: @cookiemonster the answer to the question was simply that the test case is being optimised in ways that are creating unreliable results. There is no such thing as a question without an answer. The answer to this particular question exists somewhere deep within the VM, which will suffice as an answer in my opinion.

Comment: @shennan: I didn't say there's no answer. I qualified it with "real" within the context of SO. It has the same problem as all JS micro benchmarks in that the closest thing to an answer is *"it depends"*, and that's not a good fit for SO.

Comment: @cookiemonster The (at least) 9 upvotes and 5 favourites that this question currently adorns is a sign that people have found the question valuable. Beyond the dream that SO will be void of all opinion and uncertainty, lies the reality that it won't.

Comment: @shennan: People frequently have a knee-jerk reaction to any question about performance, even ones as ridiculous as this. And when I call it ridiculous, I'm referring only to the very obviously non-real-world code example in the `a()` function, which will find no representation in production code. To call this "valuable" is quite the stretch.

Comment: @cookiemonster We agree on the answer... that the *test* is a [*pointless one*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65-RbBwZQdU). But that doesn't mean the *question* is a pointless one... is what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @shennan—I guess every cloud has a silver lining… :-)

Comment: @Bergi how very drab.

Answer (score 1):

It takes the JS engine longer to analyze the line of code when the condition gets longer and more complicated.

I believe [this JSPerf test](http://jsperf.com/or-condition5/2) can explain it well.

Answer (score -2):

true || 1 return true, it still need to check true || 1 with next coming 1(recursively). so I guess that's the reason.

Comment: consider this `true || 1 && false`, so `true || 1 ` return true, `1` certainly will not be evaluated, but this expression's following part `&& false` still need to be evaluate. so is the `true || 1 || 1 || 1 ||..` since javascript have no way to know your following expression is a sequence of `or` before runtime, it cant do any optimazation about it.